# Promoting free variables in type terms to implicit function arguments

Tags: language-design, dependent-type

In order for my question to be meaningful, I must provide some background.

---

I think it would be useful to have a dependently typed language that can infer the existence and type of an argument `a` for a function whose other parameters and/or return value have types that depend on `a`. Consider the following snippet in a language I am designing:

```
(* Backticks are used for infix functions *)
def Cat (`~>` : ob -> ob -> Type) :=
  sig
    exs id   : a ~> a
    exs `.`  : b ~> c -> a ~> b -> a ~> c
    exs lid  : id . f = f
    exs rid  : f . id = f
    exs asso : (h . g) . f = h . (g . f)
  end
```

If we make two (admittedly, unwarranted) assumptions:

1. No dependencies must exist that cannot be inferred from explicitly provided information.
2. Every free variable must be converted into an implicit argument of the last identifier introduced using `def` or `exs`.

We can interpret the above snippet as being equivalent to the following one:

```
def Cat {ob} (`~>` : ob -> ob -> Type) :=
  sig
    exs id   : all {a} -> a ~> a
    exs `.`  : all {a b c} -> b ~> c -> a ~> b -> a ~> c
    exs lid  : all {a b} {f : a ~> b} -> id . f = f
    exs rid  : all {a b} {f : a ~> b} -> f . id = f
    exs asso : all {a b c d} {f : a ~> b} {g} {h : c ~> d}
                 -> (h . g) . f = h . (g . f)
  end
```

Which is more or less the same as the following Agda snippet:

```
record Cat {ob : Set} (_⇒_ : ob → ob → Set) : Set₁ where
  field
    id   : ∀ {a} → a ⇒ a
    _∙_  : ∀ {a b c} → b ⇒ c → a ⇒ b → a ⇒ c
    lid  : ∀ {a b} {f : a ⇒ b} → id ∙ f ≡ f
    rid  : ∀ {a b} {f : a ⇒ b} → f ∙ id ≡ f
    asso : ∀ {a b c d} {f : a ⇒ b} {g} {h : c ⇒ d} → (h ∙ g) ∙ f ≡ h ∙ (g ∙ f)
```

Clearly, two unwarranted assumptions have saved us a lot of typing!

**Note:** Of course, this mechanism only works as long as the original assumptions hold. For example, we cannot correctly infer the implicit arguments of the dependent function composition operator:

```
(* Only infers (?2 -> ?3) -> (?1 -> ?2) -> (?1 -> ?3) *)
def `.` g f x := g (f x)
```

In this case, we have to explicitly provide some additional information:

```
(* If we omitted {x}, it would become an implicit argument of `.` *)
def `.` (g : all {x} (y : B x) -> C y) (f : all x -> B x) x := g (f x)
```

Which can be expanded into the following:

```
def `.` {A} {B : A -> Type} {C : all {x} -> B x -> Type}
        (g : all {x} (y : B x) -> C y) (f : all x -> B x) x := g (f x)
```

Here is the equivalent Agda definition, for comparison:

```
_∘_ : ∀ {A : Set} {B : A → Set} {C : ∀ {x} → B x → Set}
      (g : ∀ {x} (y : B x) → C y) (f : ∀ x → B x) x → C (f x)
(g ∘ f) x = g (f x)
```

**End of Note**

---

Is the mechanism described above feasible? Even better, is there any language that implements something resembling this mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like [implicit generalization in Coq.](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#implicit-generalization)